# Given a perturbation of a symmetric matrix, find an expansion for the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, power-series

> Let $A$ be a real, symmetrix $n\times n$ matrix with $n$ distinct,
>   non-zero eigenvalues, and let $V$ be a real, symmetric $n\times n$
>   matrix.
>
> Consider $A_{\varepsilon}=A+\varepsilon V$, a perturbation of $A$, where
>   $\varepsilon$ is a small number.
>
> 1. Find an expansion as an $\varepsilon$-series for the eigenvalues and
>      eigenvectors of $A_{\varepsilon}$ around the eigenvalues and
>      eigenvectors of the original matrix, $A$.
> 2. Assume that $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small that one can neglect
>      all terms of order $\varepsilon^2$ and higher in the expansion. How
>      close are the eigenvalues of $A_{\varepsilon}$ to those of $A$? What
>      about the eigenvectors?
> 3. What can we say about the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of
>      $A_{\varepsilon} $ if $A$ and $V$ are arbitrary $n\times n$ matrices?
>      You may assume that $\det A \neq 0$.

**Ideas**: If $A$ and $V$ commute (thus are simultaneously diagonalizable), there are just the linear term $\varepsilon v_{ii}$, when we look with the right basis. I'm getting the feeling I really don't know what they want me to do with this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Let's consider a particular eigenvector $v_{0}$ of $A$ where $\lambda_{0}$ is the correspondent eigenvalue. Namely, $Av_{0} = \lambda_{0}v_{0}$. 'Under the action' of $A + \epsilon V$, the eigenvalue problem becomes
$\pars{A + \epsilon V}v = \lambda v$. We expand $v$ and $\lambda$ in powers of $\epsilon$ as:
$$
v = v_{0} + v_{1}\epsilon + v_{2}\epsilon^{2} + \cdots\,,
\qquad
\lambda = \lambda_{0} + \lambda_{1}\epsilon + \lambda_{2}\epsilon^{2} + \cdots
$$ 
In order to derive the contributions to the eigenvector and eigenvalue
$\ul{\mbox{up to order}\ \epsilon}$, it's sufficient to write:
$$
\pars{A + \epsilon V}\pars{v_{0} + \epsilon v_{1}}
=
\pars{\lambda_{0} + \lambda_{1}\epsilon}\pars{v_{0} + \epsilon v_{1}}\,,
\quad
\left\vert%
\begin{array}{rcl}
Av_{0} & = & \lambda_{0}v_{0}
\\
Av_{1} + Vv_{0} & = & \lambda_{0}v_{1} + \lambda_{1}v_{0}
\end{array}\right.
$$
where we equated terms which correspond to the same power of $\epsilon$
$\pars{~\ul{\mbox{up to order}\ \epsilon}~}$.

Applying $v_{0}^{\sf T}$, by the left, to both sides of the last expression:
$$
v_{0}^{\sf T}Av_{1} + v_{0}^{\sf T}Vv_{0} = \lambda_{0}v_{0}^{\sf T}v_{1} + \lambda_{1}v_{0}^{\sf T}v_{0}
$$
Since $A$ is a symmetric matrix, we'll have
$$
\color{#ff0000}{v_{0}^{\sf T}Av_{1}} = \pars{v_{1}^{\sf T}Av_{0}}^{\sf T}
=
\pars{v_{1}^{\sf T}\lambda_{0}v_{0}}^{\sf T}
=
\color{#ff0000}{\lambda_{0}v_{0}^{\sf T}v_{1}}
\quad\mbox{such that}\quad
\lambda_{1} = {v_{0}^{\sf T}Vv_{0} \over v_{0}^{\sf T}v_{0}}
$$

> Then, $\pars{~\ul{\mbox{up to order}\ \epsilon}~}$:
> $$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
> \lambda
> \approx
> \lambda_{0} + {v_{0}^{\sf T}Vv_{0} \over v_{0}^{\sf T}v_{0}}\,\epsilon}
> $$

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to understand what you've done. $v_0$ is an eigenvector of both $A$ and $V$? How do we know that such exists?

Comment: @EricAuld I add more details right now. $\large v_{0}$ is an eigenvector of $\large A$. It does not necessarily have to be an eigenvector of $\large V$. Thanks.

Comment: Can $V$ be non-symmetric?

Comment: Can you please explain how the expansion works?I.e. $v=v_0+v_1\epsilon + v_2\epsilon^2\cdots$ and $\lambda=\lambda_0+\lambda_1\epsilon + \lambda_2\epsilon^2\cdots$. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

This is a good complex analysis problem, even though everything is stated in terms of symmetric real matrices. Complex analysis gives you a good way to find objects by using contour integrals. For example, the matrix $A$ has an orthornormal basis $\{ e_{j}\}_{j=1}^{n}$ with corresponding unique eigenvalues $\sigma(A)=\{ \lambda_{j}\}$, which can be used to write the resolvent matrix
$$
     (\lambda I -A)^{-1}x = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\lambda-\lambda_{j}}(x,e_{j})e_{j}.
$$
The resolvent has simple poles at all of the eigenvalues, and the residue matrix $R_{j}$ is the orthogonal projection onto the eigenspace with eigenvalue $\lambda_{j}$:
$$
          R_{j}x = (x,e_{j})e_{j}.
$$
Notice that, working in the norm of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$,
$$
     \|(\lambda I -A)^{-1}x\|^{2}\le \frac{1}{\mbox{dist}(\lambda,\sigma(A))^{2}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\|x\|^{2}.
$$
That is,
$$
          \|(\lambda I -A)^{-1}\| \le 1/\mbox{dist}(\lambda,\sigma(A)).
$$
If you perturb $A$ by $\epsilon V$, where $V$ is also symmetric and real, and where $\epsilon$ is real, then $(\lambda I -A-\epsilon V)$ remains invertible provided $\epsilon$ is small enough. In particular,
$$
    (\lambda I - A -\epsilon V)^{-1}=(\lambda I -A)^{-1}(I-\epsilon V(\lambda I-A)^{-1})^{-1} = (\lambda I -A)^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\epsilon^{k}(V(\lambda I -A)^{-1})^{k}.
$$
The above converges in matrix operator norm to the expected inverse if
$$
            |\epsilon|\|V\|/\mbox{dist}(\lambda,\sigma(A)) < 1\;\;\;\mbox{ or }\;\;\; |\epsilon| < \|V\|^{-1}\mbox{dist}(\lambda,\sigma(A)).
$$
By drawing a fixed system of circular contours $C_{j}$ around each $\lambda_{j}$, you can make $\epsilon$ small enough to guarantee that $(\lambda I - A-\epsilon V)^{-1}$ has all of its singularities inside these contours $C_{j}$, and to guarantee that the integrals of $(\lambda I -A-\epsilon V)^{-1}$ vary continuously with $\epsilon$ in a small range of $0$. So the eigenvalues of $A+\epsilon V$ remain in these circles for small $\epsilon$. Because the eigenspaces of $A$ all have dimension 1, then it follows that the same is true of $A+\epsilon V$ for small enough $\epsilon$; if some of the eigenspaces were to have dimension 2 or more, then there could be bifurcations in the eigenvalues.

You can argue that the dimensions of eigenspaces remain 1 for small $\epsilon$ by applying the trace to the orthogonal projection matrices $P_{j}^{\epsilon}$ defined through the contour integrals--the trace is a value which is 1 at $\epsilon=0$, remains an integer, and which must vary continuously for small $\epsilon$ because the following varies continuously with $\epsilon$:
$$
         P_{j}^{\epsilon} =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C_{j}}(\lambda I - A-\epsilon V)^{-1}d\lambda .
$$
Note: The $P_{j}^{\epsilon}$ is the projection onto all of the eigenvectors of $A+\epsilon V$ corresponding to eigenvalues enclosed by $C_{j}$. Also, $P_{j}^{\epsilon}e_{j}$ is non-zero for $\epsilon$ near $0$, and must be an eigenvector of $A+\epsilon V$ with the unique eigenvalue enclosed by $C_{j}$. I'm not sure what the normalization does to eigenvector function $\epsilon\mapsto P_{j}^{\epsilon}e_{j}$, however.

EXPANSION: I will add the explict expansion offered by the above. The expansion for the resolvent $(\lambda I - A-\epsilon V)^{-1}$, which is valid for $|\epsilon|\|V\| < \mbox{dist}(\lambda,\sigma(A))$ has first order $\epsilon$ term
$$
  (\lambda I - A)^{-1} + \epsilon(\lambda I - A)^{-1}V(\lambda I - A)^{-1}      
$$
When applied to a vector $x$, this can be written as
$$
        (\lambda I - A)^{-1}x + \epsilon\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{(x,e_{j})(Ve_{j},e_{k})e_{k}}{(\lambda-\lambda_{j})(\lambda-\lambda_{k})}
$$
Integrating over a circle enclosing only $\lambda_{j}$, which now encloses also $\lambda_{j}'$, the perturbed eigenvalue, only $(\lambda-\lambda_{j})^{-1}$ is singular. The term $(\lambda-\lambda_{j})^{-2}$ integrates to 0 because the residue is 0. The other terms $(\lambda-\lambda_{k})^{-1}(\lambda-\lambda_{j})^{-1}$ integrate to $(\lambda_{j}-\lambda_{k})^{-1}$ because $(\lambda-\lambda_{k})$ is holomorphic in the circle around $\lambda_{j}$. The projection $P_{j}x=(x,e_{j})e_{j}$ is the integral of $(\lambda I-A)^{-1}$ over the circle around $\lambda_j$. Finally, one obtains
$$
     P_{j}^{\epsilon}x = (x,e_{j})e_{j} +\epsilon\left(\sum_{k=1, (k\ne j)}^{n}\frac{(x,e_{j})(Ve_{j},e_{k})}{(\lambda_j-\lambda_k)}e_{k}\right)
$$
A good expansion of the perturbed eigenvector is, therefore, $P_j^{\epsilon} e_j$, which is
$$
          e_{j}' = e_{j} +\epsilon \sum_{k=1,(k\ne j)}^{n} \frac{(Ve_j,e_k)}{\lambda_j-\lambda_k}e_k.
$$
This needs to be normalized in length. Afterwards, the eigenvalue is $\lambda_j' = ((A+\epsilon V)e_{j}',e_{j}')$.

Comment: Dear @Disintegrating By Parts, I know it has been a loooooong time ago, but anyways :).
 What you are building is, actually, a Dyson series for the Resolvent (Green's function). My question is: whether it will preserve the completeness relation for the eigenvectors for the case, when the initial matrix and the perturbation are not real symmetric, but complex symmetric?

Comment: This is a VERY old question and a minor detail, but in the very last equation, there is a typo in the upper limit of the sum (k instead of n).

Comment: @WhiteLake : Thank you for the correction. Please check that it looks okay now.

Comment: Is this result published? Ideally something that went through peer review (StackExchange is its own form of peer review, but referees on work that cites this result tend to ask for something more formal). Thanks for this excellent explanation!