# Applications of perturbation expansion of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, approximation

Partially citing this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626425/given-a-perturbation-of-a-symmetric-matrix-find-an-expansion-for-the-eigenvalue), consider $A_{\varepsilon}=A+\varepsilon V$, a perturbation of $A$, where $\varepsilon$ is a small number (All matrices are symmetric).

A known result derived in some books that I've read is the following perturbation expansion for the eigenvectors of $A_{\varepsilon}$ ($e_j$ are the eigenvectors of $A$):

$$e_{j}' = e_{j} +\epsilon \sum_{k=1\;(k\ne j)}^{k} \frac{(Ve_j,e_k)}{\lambda_j-\lambda_k}e_k.$$

My question is are there any applications, theoretical but most importantly practical, where this expansion is used?

Comment: Look up "Fermi's golden rule"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analytic dependence of an eigenvalue from a perturbation of the linear operator is a question that has many applications in the study of dynamical systems, and it extension to linear operators in function (Hilbert) spaces is very important in quantum mechanics applications. A classical book on this subject is [here.](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kato1.pdf)